# Blob path with folder structure System.Private.CoreLib: Exception

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am using azure blobTrigger like this

With 'test' being the name of the container.

```
public static void Run([BlobTrigger("test/{name}", Connection = 
"ConnectionKey")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
```

When I add a file to the 'test' folder it runs great. Trigger gets called and does its work!! 
But our requirements is that within anywhere in the folder hierarchy of that container if a new files comes, this trigger should be able to know.

Within that 'test' container if I create a 'foo' folder and push a file in 'foo' folder I end up getting the following exception

System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: BlobTrigger_TW. System.Private.CoreLib: Input string was not in a correct format.

Blob triggers do they work with folders inside folders?

The folder hierarchy is going to get generated dynamically within the 'test' container by another program, so I will not always have the names of the folders within, that is why I would like to stick with the blob path being 'test'only and anytime a file comes in it at whatever folder level, I want the blob trigger to fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is coming from your code. In your example, `name` variable will be `foo/fileName.ext`